# Parallelize pandas with multiple class instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multiprocessing

I am trying to figure out how to run a large problem on multiple cores. I am struggling with splitting a dataframe to the different processes.

I have a class as follows:

```
class Pergroup():
    def __init__(self, groupid):
    ...

    def process_datapoint(self, df_in, group):
    ...
```

My data is a time-series, and contains events that can be grouped using the `groupid` column. I create an instance of the class for each group as so:

```
for groupname in df_in['groupid'].unique():
    instance_names.append(groupname)

holder = {name: Pergroup(name) for name in instance_names}
```

Now, for each timestamp in the dataframe, I want to call the corresponding instance (based on the group), and pass to it the dataframe at that timestamp.

I have tried the following, which does not seem to parallelize as I expect:

```
 for val in range(0, len(df_in)):
     current_group = df_in['groupid'][val]
     current_df = df_in.ix[val]
     with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
         executor.map(holder[current_group].process_datapoint, current_df, current_group)
```

I have also tried using this, which splits the df into its columns, when calling the instances:

```
Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(map(delayed(holder[current_group].process_datapoint), current_df, current_group))
```

How should I break up the dataframe such that I can still call the right instance with the right data? Basically, I am attempting to run a loop as below, with the last line running in parallel:

```
for val in range(0, len(df_in)):
    current_group = df_in['groupid'][val]
    current_df = df_in.ix[val]
    holder[current_group].process_datapoint(current_df, current_group) #This call should be initiated in as many cores as possible.
```

Comment: Might be a pretty nice use case for [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly different approach using `pool`

```
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool

# First make sure each process has its own data
groups = df_in['groupid'].unique().values
data = [(group_id, holder[group_id], df_in.ix[group_id]) 
        for group for groups]

# Prepare a function that can take this data as input
def help_func(current_group, holder, current_df):
    return holder.process_datapoint(current_df, current_group)

# Run in parallel
with Pool(processes=4) as p:
    p.map(help_func, data)
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, I seem to get a `Can't pickle <function <lambda>` error.  I am trying to figure out why that might be ...

Comment: I got around the pickling issue by writing a function like this `def help_func(in_val):
    in_val[1].process_datapoint(in_val[2], in_val[0])`. However, when I run this on my data, I would expect that there are only as many instances as `groupid`, however for some reason it seems to make more instances. Do you have any pointers here?

Comment: Oh true, forgot about the lambda. Indeed a simple solution. I would expect it to make as many instances as the data, which is `len(data)` which should be `len(df_in)`.

Comment: Changed the post to give you a pointer what I mean: you will get as many instances as you have data points in data. So if data should only have one item per group, than it will be something like above :) Really hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I should have made my previous comment clearer. The issue that I was facing was that: I know for sure that `data` will contain an unique number of `holder[group_id]`. However, when I run Pool, and look at the different instances that have been called (through help_func), I noticed that there are new instances that are being spun up for some group_ids. Could it be that there is some reason due to which new instances are created? I had no idea if that could happen.

Comment: It may well be the case that I have some bug within the `process_datapoint()`, which dies, and a new instance is created later. May be. I need to look closer at this.

Comment: Did you discover what it was? :)

Comment: Yes, it was an issue with concurrent threads and some bugs too. I needed to introduce locks before the function call, which fixed the issue...

Answer (score 0):

I had at some point a similar problem; as I can completely adapt to your question, I hope you can transpose and make this fit to your problem:

```
    import multiprocessing
    from joblib import Parallel, delayed

    maxbatchsize = 10000 #limit the amount of data dispatched to each core 
    ncores = -1 #number of cores to use
    data = pandas.DataFrame() #<<<- your dataframe

    class DFconvoluter():
         def __init__(self, myparam):
              self.myparam = myparam
         def __call__(self, df):
              return df.apply(lamda row: row['somecolumn']*self.myparam)

    nbatches = max(math.ceil(len(df)/maxbatchsize), ncores)
    g = GenStrategicGroups( data['Key'].values, nbatches ) #a vector telling which row should be dispatched to which batch

    #-- parallel part
    def applyParallel(dfGrouped, func):
        retLst = Parallel(n_jobs=ncores)(delayed(func)(group) for _, group in dfGrouped)
        return pd.concat(retLst)
    out = applyParallel(data.groupby(g), Dfconvoluter(42)))'
```

what is left is to write, how you'd like to group the batches together, for me this had to be done in a fashion so that rows, where values in the 'keys'-column where similar had to stay together:

```
def GenStrategicGroups(stratify, ngroups):
    ''' Generate a list of integers in a grouped sequence, 
    where grouped levels in stratifiy are preserved.
    '''
    g = []
    nelpg = float(len(stratify)) / ngroups

    prev_ = None
    grouped_idx = 0
    for i,s in enumerate(stratify):
        if i > (grouped_idx+1)*nelpg: 
            if s != prev_:
                grouped_idx += 1
        g.append(grouped_idx)
        prev_ = s
    return g
```